# C - reading a file and appending data to another

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to open a file (that wants to be a small archive) and I want to copy another file content in it. The code is the following:

```
FILE * arch;
FILE * par;

void read_words (FILE *f) 
{
char x[1024];
while (fscanf(f," %s",x)==1) 
   {
    fprintf(arch," %s", x);
   }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
char * nome;
nome = argv[1];

archivio = scrivi(getcwd(NULL, 0), nome);
arch = fopen(archivio, "w+");

par = fopen(argv[2], "r+");

read_words(par);

return 0;
}
```

Please assume that "archivio" is a working path.

i call the function as follows: `./a.out archiveName FilePath`.

All i want to do is opening this archive, then, after some `fprintf`s (that work correctly, not shown here) opening another file and write its content in archive. 
The problem is in the function read_words. It works if taken alone (I took code from here), but if I insert that here, it doesn't work, because it doesn't even enter in `while (fscanf(f," %s",x)==1)`. In fact archive file is always empty.

Can you help me find out why?

Thanks

PS: This is an example text i tried to insert: 
    `La funzione mkbkp si occupa della creazione di un archivio contenente i file e le      cartelle passate come parametri.`

The strange thing is that if you make a c file with only read_words, it works fine.

Comment: It doesn't work in what sense?

Comment: Can you tell us in which way it doesn't work?

Comment: You think this code is long?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `arch`?

Comment: I have added some explanations to code.

Comment: If it's not going into the loop, `fscanf()` must be returning something other than 1. Add some code to print what it's returning.

Comment: `par = fopen(argv[2], "r+");` <- check whether `par` is `NULL` (ditto for `arch`).

Comment: how can i see if it is null? i tried to print it but it says it's an incompatible pointer type

Comment: `if(NULL==(par=fopen(argv[2], "r+"))){ perror("par"); exit(1);}`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It's not null. it doesn't enter `then` branch.

Comment: @DanielFischer arch is not null (`fprintf`s work properly, but not this function)

Comment: Okay, so the files seem to be open. Then check the return value of `fscanf` (and fix its format string; the `%s` conversion skips initial whitespace, so the space is not necessary, but you should limit the number of characters it may read), `int conversions; while((conversions = fscanf(f, "%1023s", x)) == 1) { ... } if (conversions == 0) { /* ??? */ } else if (!feof(f)) { /* conversion failed without having tried to read past the end of file */ }`.

Comment: @DanielFischer `conversions` is not zero. Do i have to change something in `fprintf`or `fscanf` attributes?

Comment: Well, you definitely should change the format string to prevent buffer overruns, and when the `fscanf` stops returning 1, it'd be nice to have some information on why, if the file ends with whitespace, you should get 0, otherwise `EOF`. Then a `feof` check, and check `errno` (`#include <errno.h>`, and call `perror("fscanf failure");` to see what error you got `if (errno)`).

Comment: Uhm.. It doesn'enter in `while`, nor in `conversions==0` if, nor in `feof`..  I put a print after `char x[1024]`and before `while`, and it reaches that point, but it doesn't go further.

I used code you wrote some comments above.

Comment: Check `errno`. If it doesn't enter the `while` loop, the very first scan already fails.

Comment: Are you certain your input file is a text file? What operating system are you on? It might be possible that there is an embedded binary character that is making the C file input handling believe it encountered EOF on the first line.

Comment: @user315052 I am on Mac OSX (Snow Leopard) and i have handled only text files.

Comment: @AndreaGottardi: Can you put the first few lines of your input file into your question?

Comment: @DanielFischer errno doesn't return any issue.

Comment: Can you check `ferror(f)` and verify that `fscanf` returns `EOF` (if it returns neither 1 nor 0, it can't legitimately return anything else, but just in case)?

Comment: fscanf reaches EOF.. But it doesn't even enter in `while`.. Maybe fopen doesn't recognize files without an extension?

Comment: It isn't related to an extension.

Comment: i have to copypaste the entire code in a new file.. tried it some time ago with another program and it solved the problem i was getting crazy about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the way you describe the behavior of your program, I can only suppose that you are not reading the file that you want to be reading.  Try using this function:

```
void show_file (const char *filename, FILE *out) {
    int c;
    FILE *file;
    fprintf(out, "%s(%s) BEGIN\n", __func__, filename);
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file) {
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            fputc(c, out);
        }
        fclose(file);
    } else {
        fprintf(out, "%s: failed to open file '%s' (%d)\n", __func__, filename, errno);
    }
    fprintf(out, "%s(%s) END\n", __func__, filename);
}
```

You can call this function from your `main` like this:

```
show_file(argv[2], stderr);
```

Make sure the path to the file and the contents of the file match your expectations.